# WPF control develop idea

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, wpf-controls

OK, I want to create a control that is like a `Stackpanel` with `TextBlock` on the left, something like:

[image: Picture]

The `TextBlock` need to be editable. So, the question is from whom I need to inherit to make that since cannot from `Stackpanel`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is basically a [`HeaderedItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol.aspx) with a custom [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx).

The template could be a `Grid` with two columns, one containing a rotated `ContentPresenter` which is bound to the header properties, on the right you would have an `ItemsPresenter` for the items.

e.g.

```
<Style TargetType="HeaderedItemsControl"> <!-- Implicitly applied -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HeaderedItemsControl">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header">
                        <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                        </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                    <ItemsPresenter Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
<HeaderedItemsControl Header="Lorem Ipsum" ItemsSource="ABCDEF"/>
```

Comment: @PredragPejic: Added example, you might want to hook up some more properties using [`TemplateBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx)