# WPF User Control XAML binding

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, wpf-controls

I have following user control:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="HeaderedItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="HeaderedItemsControl">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe Script"
                                   Text="{Binding ElementName=myHeaderedItemsControl.Header, Path=Category, Mode=OneWay}"
                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="Olive" 
                                   Margin="20"
                                   FontSize="50"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   Name="myText"/>
                        <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">        
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>-->
    <HeaderedItemsControl Name="myHeaderedItemsControl"  Header="Predrag">
    </HeaderedItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

and basically what i want is to bind `Textblock` text property to `HeaderedItemsControl` header property.

Comment: Why are you not just using a `ContentPresenter` with `ContentSource="Header"` as i showed in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957757/wpf-control-develop-idea)?

Comment: because i did not managed to set appropriate style on it...

Comment: You could wrap it in a `Border` and set the properties there, that's usually how it's done. (Also text properties can be set via attached properties as well, e.g. `TextElement.Foreground`)

Comment: Why is `ContentPresenter` a better way?

Comment: Because it is made for this, also it does not restrict the content to plain text. Besides binding to the header it also allows you to hook up the `HeaderTemplate` and `HeaderTemplateSelector` (this happens automatically when you use [`ContentSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.contentsource.aspx))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
```

Don't know however, what the `Path=Category` means.

Comment: Is there a way to add other UIElement from c# code behind to HeaderedItemsControl because there is no Children property?